# ReactJS -Api Data is loading only if i refresh screen twice and data is vanishing if i refresh

Tags: reactjs, api

i had the react screens developed with the static data , now i am trying to get that data from db using api call but screen data is loading untill i click twice and if i refresh the page the entire data is clearing off

I am new to react , it would be really helpful if some one suggest me the solution

Comment: You will have to post the relevant code

Comment: code sample would be beneficial

Comment: export default function DataTable() {
 const navigate =
  useNavigate();
 const classes = useStyles();
 useEffect(() => {
  const c = callApi().then(
   (e) => {
    return e;
   }
  );

  const b =
   Promise.resolve(c);
  console.log(b);

  b.then((value) => {
   const rows_up = [];
   var i = 1;
   for (const s of value) {
    const a = {
     id: i,
     invokePath: s.invokePath,
     FunctionId: s.functionId,
     application:
      s.application,
    };
    rows_up.push(a);
    i++;
   }
   console.log(rows);
   rows = rows_up;
  });
 }, []);
}

Comment: i have added in the comment